# How to correctly use a for loop for plotting multiple lines from a csv in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, plot

I am in the processing of learning Python (Basic question coming) and I have lots of data that comes out of some analyses as CSV files that look like the following:

[image: Example data table]

I am trying to recreate the plot below (currently I do things like this in Excel and with the volume of data coming out and the complexity of the visualizations, I want to make things more efficient.

[image: Plot I am trying to recreate]

I tried to use the concept of For Loops to plot a line for each different "SectionName" in that column but am clearly missing something.

```
#read CSV
df=pd.read_csv('/Users/F/Documents/Data/LinesLoopTest.csv')

#Make Variables from dataframe columns
Value = df['Value']
Position = df['Xposition']
Section = df['SectionName']

#Setup Figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,3))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.set_title('Sections')
ax1.set_xlabel("XPosition")
ax1.set_ylabel("Value")

#plot lines by SectionName
for name in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
    plt.plot(Position, Value)

plt.show()
```

I realize this is a simple question, I just have not found an explanation so far where I can actually understand the process to the point that I can recreate it and then build on it.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)  on the `SectionName` and then plot the groups

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for section, group in df.groupby('SectionName'):
    group.plot(x='Xposition', y='Value', ax=ax, label=section)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @sheldore, if I want to put each line in each separate plot, what should be the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

I came late, so I did a pretty much a "copy/pastable" version of Sheldore's answer (His answer should me be approved)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

# intialise data of lists. 
data = {'SectionName':['A','A','A', 'B','B','B', 'C','C','C'], 
        'Xpos':[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 
        'Val':[0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.4, 1.3, 0.2, 1.2, 1.9, 1.8]} 

# Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for section, group in df.groupby('SectionName'):
    group.plot(x='Xpos', y='Val', ax=ax, label=section)
plt.show()
```

Comment: @Sheldore and Ivan (SO only lets me address one person), this is exactly what I needed, thank you! I see what you're doing with the groupby, excellent!

Out of interest (this may need to be a separate question) is there a way to add another line that is the average line of all the "SectionNames." I can always make this a new question. Either way, thanks for the help!